# Change UIView colour using sender.tag

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have seen `sender.tag` normally being used for buttons but was wondering if it could be used for a `UIView` ? 
This is the scenario : I have a few text inputs with no borders and just under each one I have a thin (about 3px) UIView which is dark grey. So it appears that each text field has a bottom border. For each field that is empty I want to change the UIView colour to red. I thought that instead of creating an outlet for every single one, I could just create one and give them different tag numbers and change colour based on that but I am not sure how.

So, this is if just one field is empty :

```
if userName!.isEmpty {
   validateUnderline.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
}
```

As I am quite new to swift I don't know if this is possible using UIView. This is what I did with a button :

```
@IBAction func notePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    playSound(soundFileName: soundArray[sender.tag - 1])

}
```

Comment: You can use `tag` with any `UIView`.

Answer (score 0):

1-You can use IBOutletCollection for your requirement.

@IBOutlet var underLineVIew: [UIView]!

connect all your view to above IBOutlet and use it anywhere for ex-

underLineVIew[0].backgroundColor  = UIColor.yellowColor()

2- you can also try  UITextField extension.

```
extension UITextField {
 func setBottomBorder() {
   self.borderStyle = .none
   self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
   self.layer.masksToBounds = false
   self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
   self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 1.0)
   self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
   self.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for delay. I decided to do something else instead which was to make the placeholder text red if the field was not filled in, like this:  `emailTxt.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Email", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red])`